# Spring xd. Source waiting sink completion

Tags: java, spring, dsl, spring-xd

Is it possible to implemet (write dsl query)?

`source` must waiting while `sink` processing is not completed.

`sink` - completed -> `source` starts.

Example:

`First stream` writing to DB some info (`jdbc sink`)

`Second stream` must do something only if all information are stored in DB (`first stream`).

I have only one solution for this moment - write custom source (with jdbc-sink inside)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a `SpringXD` problem, this is rather a `algorithm` problem.

Frankly, you can use a `lock` in the `sink module` to indicate the status of the `loading process`. and set the `source module` to wait when work is not done.

Hope this would help you.